# Skeleton is an ambiguous tag

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, ambiguous-tags

The [skeleton](/questions/tagged/skeleton) tag [info tab](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/skeleton/info) says that Skeleton is a Wordpress theme, but it has been used ([20 times total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/skeleton)) for several different things and looks like none of them is related to Wordpress.

For me, as a front-end developer, Skeleton is primarily associated with [Skeleton CSS Boilerplate](http://www.getskeleton.com/). In this sense tag was used [3 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/skeleton+css), those should be retaged to [skeleton-boilerplate](/questions/tagged/skeleton-boilerplate) (or even [skeleton-css-boilerplate](/questions/tagged/skeleton-css-boilerplate)) with tag's description updated appropriately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oy, that one is a bit of a mess.  I saw questions related to the following:

- Tracking skeletons (people) in Kinect
- Determining bones in images/x-rays
- Animation of 3d models
- A framework directory in Ruby on Rails
- CSS boilerplate system

That said, [skeleton](/questions/tagged/skeleton) wasn't good on it's own, and all of the questions have sufficent other tags to identify them (as well as the word "skeleton" in the post).  With that, I've manually removed the [skeleton](/questions/tagged/skeleton) tag from those questions.

Where it's appropriate, I've added the [skeleton-css-boilerplate](/questions/tagged/skeleton-css-boilerplate) tag to the question and I've created a tag wiki for the tag.

As a side effect, I've also manually removed the [bones](/questions/tagged/bones) tag from the system.